# Gather all broken links (Link-checker) in view

Tags: 7, navigation

I just installed the Link-checker module which seems nice for my needs. But I don't see a way to gather all the nodes with broken links, for example a view or block.

Is there any way to collect all these nodes with broken links in a view/block?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this would involve either a custom module, or a patch to the link-checker module, with an implementation of [hook_views_data](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21docs%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7). This requires some coding skills and understanding of databases.

One option is to try the [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module, which supposedly is capable of automatically deriving the required information by looking at the table structure. I've never tried it though, so whether or not it works, or how well it works, I cannot say. From looking at the modules schema, it looks like the interesting tables are:

D7 "linkchecker_block_custom", "linkchecker_comment", "linkchecker_node", "linkchecker_link"

D6 "linkchecker_boxes", "linkchecker_comments", "linkchecker_nodes", "linkchecker_links"

Comment: Right now, I'm writing my own custom block. I already figured out it would end in custom coding :) Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the [Link checker Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkchecker_views) module

> Link checker integration with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, so to be able to produce custom reports of the data collected by linkchecker

For example you can create a new report sorting the links by "last date checked desc" and show that date, or you could filter the report at your pleasure.

Right now there is a dev version available. So test it on local before use on live sites.